# Find CDF of a random variable constructed from another r.v. denoting a randomly picked point

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Given $X(\omega) = \omega, \forall\omega \in \Omega = [0, 6]$, the range being uniformly distributed, that denotes the waiting time in a queue such that one waits no more than 6 minutes, the CDF of $F_X(\omega) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            0 & \quad \omega \in (-\infty,0) \\
            \frac{\omega}{6} & \quad \omega \in [0,6)\\
1 &\quad \omega \in [6,\infty)
        \end{array}
    \right.$

Million dollar question: what is $F_Y(\omega)$ for $Y(\omega) = \frac{\omega^3}{3}$, and $\mathbb{P}(Y\leq9)$?

We know that $F_Y(\omega) = F_X(\frac{\omega^3}{3})$, by definition. Does that mean it suffices to plug in $\frac{\omega^3}{3}$ instead of $\omega$ in $F_X(\omega)$? i.e. $F_Y(\omega) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            0 & \quad \omega \in (-\infty,0) \\
            \frac{\omega^3}{18} & \quad \omega \in [0,6)\\
1 &\quad \omega \in [6,\infty)
        \end{array}
    \right.$

Meaning that $\mathbb{P}(Y\leq9) = 1$?

Comment: If $0<x<6$ you know $P(X\le x)=\frac x6$.  If $Y=\frac{X^3}3$  - a strictly increasing function - then $P(Y\le y)=P(\frac{X^3}3\le y) =P({X^3}\le 3y) = P(X\le \sqrt[3]{3y}) = \frac{\sqrt[3]{3y}}{6}$ at least for $0<y<\frac{6^3}{3}=72$

Comment: i would kindly take your comment as an answer, sir. thank you, you're amazing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Requested from comment:*

If $0<x<6$ you know $P(X≤x)=\frac x6$.

If $Y=\frac{X^3}3$, a strictly increasing function, then

$P(Y\le y)=P(\frac{X^3}3\le y) =P({X^3}\le 3y) = P(X\le \sqrt[3]{3y}) = \frac{\sqrt[3]{3y}}{6}$
at least for $0<y<\frac{6^3}{3}=72$